# How can I set environment variables in fish?

Tags: fish

I'm new to the fish shell, and just trying to set my $EDITOR variable so that's it's persistent across sessions and reboots. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Running `set -gx EDITOR vim` from the command line.
2. Running `set -Ux EDITOR vim` from the command line.
3. Running those commands, prefixed by `set -e EDITOR` to unset any previous value.
4. Adding the above commands to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file (it complains `set: Warning: universal scope selected, but a global variable “EDITOR” exists.`)
5. Uninstalling `oh-my-fish` and removing all fish configs to start from scratch.

No matter what I do, the EDITOR variable always ends up being `/usr/bin/nano` whenever I open a new terminal, start a new session, or reboot. What's even more strange is that in `~/.config/fish/fishd.my-hostname`, I see `SET_EXPORT EDITOR vim`, and nothing about nano. Is this some kind of fish default? If so, how can I set this correctly?

Edit: I'm running Fish 2.6.0 on Antergos Linux.

Answer (score 12):

First, the fish config file is ~/.config/fish/config.fish. Editing the file you named won't have any effect. Second, fish does not have any default for, nor does it set, the EDITOR or VISUAL variables. So whatever is setting it to /usr/bin/nano is a customization unique to your system.

If you `set -Ux EDITOR vim` and do not set it in config.fish it should be set to vim even if it is already set when fish starts. Run that set command then do `set -U | grep EDITOR` and `env | grep EDITOR` to see that it is set as a universal variable and exported. Now type `fish` to start a sub-shell. Run the previous two commands and you should see that it is still set to the same value. Now type `set -U EDITOR nano` in the sub-shell followed by `exit`. In the earlier shell you should now see that EDITOR is set to nano.

Personally I don't like to use uvars for this since at the moment they are per-machine. I just do `set -gX EDITOR (type -p vim)` in my ~/.config/fish/config.fish. This ensures that if I start fish on a new machine on which I've installed my ~/.config/fish directory I get my expected defaults.

The other reason not to use a uvar in this way is that the resolution order is local scope, global scope, universal scope. Since environment vars imported when fish starts running are placed in the global scope they will shadow the uvar you defined. Do not export universal variables. It is unlikely to produce the desired results. Simply `set -gx` the var in your config.fish script.

P.S., When asking questions of this nature you should always include pertinent facts such as the OS you're using and the fish version.

Comment: Right you are. I've edited my question to reflect that. I can run the commands you describe, and they work fine, but I guess the problem is making the variable persistent across sessions. If I run `set -Ux EDITOR vim` and then open a new terminal and run `echo $EDITOR`, it shows `/usr/bin/nano`. I'm trying to set `$EDITOR` so that it's persistent across everything.

Comment: Then there is something in your fish config that is setting it to nano. Fish does not do that. Setting it as a uvar works unless you subsequently do `set -gx EDITOR nano` in your config.fish or a related script. Try this instead `mkdir /tmp/fish` then `env HOME=/tmp/fish fish` then do the set EDITOR as a uvar and start another fish with the same env command. You should find that EDITOR is set as expected.

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing in my fish config that's setting EDITOR to nano. My entire `~/.config/fish` directory is up at https://github.com/JonathanReeve/dotfiles/tree/master/dotfiles/.config/fish and I've grepped it, and there's no mention of nano. So it's getting set some other way. You'll see that my fishd.jon-laptop file has the variable correctly set there, so fish is loading another file after loading my config, and that's setting it to nano. You're right that I can make a new fish config in /tmp, and set the var there, but it still has EDITOR as nano.

Comment: Okay, I see what is going on. From the documentation: "There may be many variables with the same name, but different scopes. When using a variable, the variable scope will be searched from the inside out, i.e. a local variable will be used rather than a global variable with the same name, a global variable will be used rather than a universal variable with the same name." Environment vars imported when fish starts are set as global vars and therefore take precedence over the universal var. I've edited my answer above to make this clear and will add an entry to the fish FAQ to clarify this.

Comment: I guess then the question is, what script is fish running on startup that's setting EDITOR to /bin/nano?

Comment: Fish is not running anything to set it to nano. It's already been exported into the environment by whatever program launched fish. Or launched the program that launched fish, etc. So, for example, if you start fish from bash then any of its config scripts (e.g., /etc/profile) might be setting it. You can ensure your uvar is used and the current environment is ignored by adding `set -eg EDITOR` to you config.fish script.